# Node.js and MYSQL handle disconnect

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have cot the following code from a web search and can connect from a client and return data from the database ok.

This is setup on a Mac at home. If I lose the internet connection (usually doing a router re-start to get a faster connection) it recovers okay. However if the connection is down for a while I still have my node.js stuff working but the MYSQL connection is dead. I have to stop and start node.js to re-establish the connection.

```
var db_config = {
host     : 'www.xxxx.com',
user     : 'xxx',
password : 'xxx',
};
var connection;

function handleDisconnect() {
connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // Recreate the connection, since
                                              // the old one cannot be reused.

connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
  console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
  setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to        reconnect,
}                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script    to
});                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
                                      // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
connection.on('error', function(err) {
console.log('db error', err);
if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
  handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
} else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
  throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
}
});
}

handleDisconnect();
```

What is the best way to ensure the connection recovers?

MrWarby.